# Bad image rendering in ListView in Win XP

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, rendering, thumbnails

I have problem with rendering images in ListView in winforms app based on .NET 3.5.

In ListView control I use LargeImageList as thumbnails.

App works correctly in Win 7 - images in thumbnails are OK but if app runs in Win XP images in thumbnails are rendered bad.

Difference between rendering in Win 7 and Win Xp is on this [image].

What can cause this behavior?

EDITED: Thank you all for response and advice.It’s solved. I use another control not winforms listview.

Comment: Can you post some code? And maybe images that are slightly bigger so that we can tell what *exactly* is different, other than one is ugly/messed up?

Comment: @Cody Gray. App code is same, test data are same, but rendering in Win XP is different as in Win 7. Which part of app code you want to see?

Comment: Well, I was thinking code to reproduce the problem. This isn't something I've ever seen before, so I don't know of a common cause. Also, it looks like someone's edit accidentally removed your image. I'm not sure why, but I fixed that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the **free** ObjectListView control for this purpose. You can download it  from http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net.

#### Basic Implementation

1. Replace your regular ListView control with an ObjectListView.
2. Create a class that contains the fields you want to display on the ObjectListView.
   This is necessary because OLV does not directly use a *ListViewItem* to display elements.
3. Create columns (in code) in the OLV and specify the property (from step 2) that will be displayed for the column.
4. Set the `ImageGetter` property of the column for which you want to display an image (usually the first column) to a function that returns an `Image`, `string` or `int` which corresponds to the image you want to display for the item.
   If a function returns `string` or `int`, then the image in the OLV's `LargeImageList` or `SmallImageList` will be displayed for the item.
5. Create an `Enumerable` collection of the items you want to display and attach it to the OLV using the `SetObjects` or `AddObjects` method.
6. In the function for returning the image to be displayed for an item, render the image with GDI (or anyhow you want) and return it for display in the OLV.

Answer (score 0):

You may check out [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) component. We made substantial effort to enable thumbnails of arbitrary sizes:

[image]

The rendering uses GDI+ so the result looks the same on XP and Windows 7 (except for selections, which are based on Windows Theme, of course).

.NET ListView is a Win32 control wrapper so the looks depend largely on the operating system, we made a control written fully in managed code just to avoid these problems.

Comment: But this library is not free :(